# How to Add A Rel Filter to All Links?

Tags: functions, filters, links

How can I add a filter in the functions.php to all links tags?

Basically I am needing to add a rel="tooltip" to all my anchor tags within WordPress.

I appreciate the help.

Thnx

Comment: I'm guessing this is for a JavaScript tooltip? If so, why not just query all anchors in the document?

Comment: That will break anytime the plugin is updated by the plugin author. [Its a WP plug]

Comment: I don't think he's suggesting you modify the plugin, add it via your own plugin or the theme.